# People guessing program (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make a guessing game-type thing in javascript. I want it so that I can just keep adding new people and questions without changing the other code and it will work just fine. Now this is what I've got so far, and it seems like it should be working, but its acting very unpredictable and weird. Could someone please take a look at my code and see where I went wrong?

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yf6Sy/)

Here:

```
// ORDER: Name, Age, Gender, Glasses

var peopleremaining = [
["Evan",17,"male",false],
["Liam",10,"male",false],
["Logan",15,"female",false],
["Brynn",7,"female",false],
["Caz",37,"male",true]
];

var questions = [
["Is the person you're thinking of older than 16?",1,16],
["Is the person you're thinking of male?",2,"male"],
["Is the person you're thinking of older than 10?",1,10],
["Does the person you're thinking of wear eyeglasses?",3,true]
 ];

 var randomquestion;
 var randomquestionnumber;

 function newquestion() {
randomquestionnumber = [Math.floor((Math.random()*questions.length))];
randomquestion = questions[randomquestionnumber];
document.getElementById("mainheading").innerHTML = randomquestion[0];
 }

 function buttonpressed(option) {
var questionsubject = randomquestion[1];
var questionvalue = randomquestion[2];
var peopleremaininglength = peopleremaining.length;

if (option == "yes") {

if (questionsubject == 1) {
    for (var t=0;t<peopleremaininglength;t++) {
        if (peopleremaining[t][questionsubject] < questionvalue) {
            peopleremaining.splice(t, 1)
        }
    }
}

else {
    for (var t=0;t<peopleremaininglength;t++) {
        if (peopleremaining[t][questionsubject] != questionvalue) {
            peopleremaining.splice(t, 1)
        }
    }
}

}

else {

if (questionsubject == 1) {
    for (var t=0;t<peopleremaininglength;t++) {
        if (peopleremaining[t][questionsubject] >= questionvalue) {
            peopleremaining.splice(t, 1)
        }
    }
}

else {
    for (var t=0;t<peopleremaininglength;t++) {
        if (peopleremaining[t][questionsubject] == questionvalue) {
            peopleremaining.splice(t, 1)
        }
    }
}   

}

questions.splice(randomquestionnumber, 1);

if (peopleremaining.length == 1) {
    alert("You are thinking of " + peopleremaining[0][0]);
}

else {
    newquestion();
}

 }
```

Comment: Please explain clearly what exactly is going wrong with your program.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are iterating over each element of the "peopleremaining" array, but within that loop you are modifying the array.

One quick way around this would be to break out of the loop like so:

```
        for (var t = 0; t < peopleremaininglength; t++) {
            if (peopleremaining[t][questionsubject] < questionvalue) {
                peopleremaining.splice(t, 1)
                t = peopleremaininglength; // Add this line to break out of the loop
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This sort of makes sense to me, but i'm still a little confused as to what's going on here. And I tried this and it doesn't seem to totally fix it...

Answer (score 0):

You made typical mistake - you modifying iterated object inside iteration.